# How to identify what causes Visual Studio to use to much memory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2013

we are using Visual Studio 2013 with latest updates installed. Our solution(s) contains about 20 to 30 C# library and asp.net projects. We also have some extensions installed such as Resharper, VSCommands and NCrunch (all latest versions as well).

After working a couple of minutes on a solution the memory of Visual studio increases to more than 2GB of RAM. The IDE is becoming very unresponsive.

Usually i have to close a solution after working with it after 1 or 2 hours.

When not closing VS myself the RAM usage goes up to 3GB+ and VS crashes (probably because VS is still a 32bit application)

How can i identify what causes Visual Studio to use so much memory?

Thanks

(I realized that ncrunch is also using a lot of RAM when executing our tests. Therefor i have disabled it. It takes a couple of minutes longer for VS to use so much ram when ncrunch is disabled but the problem remains)

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling all of your extensions, then adding them back one-by-one while checking performance?

Comment: no, just enabling and disabling ncrunch and resharper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We identified that the latest perforce plugin for visual studio (p4vs: p4vs11_2014.2.93.1619.vsix) was the cause for VS to grow in memory usage.

We downgraded to p4vs11_2013.3.78.1524.vsix. This fixed the problem. 
(Also it seems that p4vs11_2014.1.85.4506.vsix is still working)

Comment: How did you identify it? Did you run some kind of VS process manager?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into a similar scenario on my end. But mine was purely resharper.

I had personally used the following things to optimize the performance.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Ultimate+Guide+to+Speeding+Up+ReSharper+(and+Visual+Studio)

For huge projects, I usually turn off the solution wide analysis for it.